# R: square plotting region lost when plotting as pdf

Tags: r

This has certainly been asked before, but I can't find a solution. I would like to plot some data with a *perfect* square as bounding box. With `par(pty="s")` this is easy, but once I save the plot as a pdf file, the square is lost. As I understand, this is because `pdf()` uses `paper="special"` as default and thus respects `width` and `height` (which does not give a perfect square since we have axis labels). But specifying other `paper` options did not help.

```
## the bounding rectangle in the following plot is a perfect square...
U <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol=2)
par(pty="s")
plot(U, type="p", xlab="U_1", ylab="U_2")

## ... however, not anymore if the plot is generated as a .pdf
pdf(file="U.pdf", width=6, height=6)
par(pty="s")
plot(U, type="p", xlab="U_1", ylab="U_2")
dev.off()
```

Comment: are you sure it's not square? Adobe Acrobat tells me it is.

Comment: Dear baptiste, thanks for helping. Indeed, it gives me a square. I was mislead by a different resolution I used on my old display. Should have thought about that...